# innerHTML in javaScript for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have used innerHtml in my java based web application. JavaScript works fine with Mozilla Firefox but it is not working in InternetExplorer.

Could you please tell me how to make it work in Internet Explorer too. or what is substitute of innerHTML in IE.

Code is:

```
function show() {    
  if('number' == typeof this.rowIndex) {
    var rn = this.rowIndex;
    var cell = tableRows[rn].cells;
    employeeCode = cell[0].innerHTML;
    //..........
  }
}
```

Thank and regards

Answer (score 7):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) eliminates problems like this in nearly all cases. It handles the minor differences between major browsers so you can do simple things like:

```
$("div.summary").html(); /* Gets HTML from <div class="summary"> */
$("div.summary").html("Hello"); /* Sets the HTML */
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "always," but certainly most of the time :)

Comment: @Jonathan: It's a running joke, that's all. I know it's not "always" the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML, to be cross-browser, needs something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function show (where,what) {
   var ie = document.all;  // Internet Explorer
   var ns = document.getElementById && !document.all;  // Firefox, Netscape, other browsers
   if(ie) { 
      eval("document.all."+where).innerHTML = what; }
   else if(ns) {
      document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = what; }
}

</script>

<a href="javascript:show('display','Hallo')">try</a>
<div id="display"></div>
```

As I found in  http://usenet.manifestinteractive.com/manifestElementControl.html?/usenet/manifestElementControl.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `innerText` in place of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if the browser is using internet explorer then get the version. after you have the browsers version you can use an if statement to tell it to use InnerText for IE and InnerHTML for the rest of the browsers.

InnerText is the alternate way of InnerHTML for Internet Explorer.  Hope this helps.

```
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for MSIE x.x;
 var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
}

 //detect if IE version is greater than 1 then deletes row content
if (ieversion>=1) {
row.innerText = '';
} else {
row.innerHTML = '';
 }
```